# What is the equivalent linux API for WaitForMultipleObjects() and WSAEnumNetworkEvents()?

Tags: linux, windows, porting

What is the equivalent linux API for WaitForMultipleObjects() and WSAEnumNetworkEvents()?
Can we use pthread_cond_wait() for WaitForMultipleObjects?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WaitForSingleObject and WaitForMultipleObjects equivalent in linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719580/waitforsingleobject-and-waitformultipleobjects-equivalent-in-linux)

Answer (score 8):

For developers coming from a Windows background, we faced the same issue when porting some code from Win32 to pthreads [and created an open source (MIT-licensed) library](https://neosmart.net/blog/2011/waitformultipleobjects-and-win32-events-for-linux-and-read-write-locks-for-windows/) called [pevents](https://github.com/NeoSmart/PEvents) which implements `WaitForMultipleObjects()` on Linux, with support for both auto and manual reset events. It should behave in the same way as WIN32 events on Windows do.

Comment: sweet -- I've struggled with an implementation for a long time.

Comment: Doesn't pevents realize waiting by polling? If it does, its functions are not equivalents of the `WaitForMultipleObject()` API which performs the wait by blocking. (And not eating up CPU time.)

Comment: @mg30rg I'm not sure why you would say/assume that. pevents is fully asynchronous and event-driven, using native posix synchronization primitives to replicate the behavior of the Windows' ones. It's most-decidedly *not* a polling solution.

Answer (score 3):

Well there is no straightforward API in Linux, that does the `WaitForMultipleObjects()` equivalent.

[WaitForSingleObject and WaitForMultipleObjects equivalent in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719580/waitforsingleobject-and-waitformultipleobjects-equivalent-in-linux) contains answer to the first part and perhaps a better explanation too.

For `WSAEnumNetworkEvents()`, in Linux, use `poll()` or `select()` based on your requirements. Another application `libevent` might also be useful.

Reference:

- [`poll(3)` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/poll)
- [`select(3)` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/select)
- [libevent](http://libevent.org/)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, if select() is used for this, then what should we use for WSAEventSelect()? Or should we use select for WSAEventSelect() and poll for WSAEnumNetworkEvents()??

Comment: If I am not wrong, select() is used to register the new socket for read/write/close network events and poll() as you suggested would be used to check which network event (read/write/close) has occured..?

Comment: [This link](http://www.unixguide.net/network/socketfaq/2.14.shtml) will answer your queries better. :)

Comment: I would also suggest going through [this link](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/rzab6/xnonblock.htm) to gain a better understanding with examples. If you still need help, I will be happy to help. :)