# WaitForMultipleObjects equivalent in Linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, event-handling, linux-device-driver, sleep

Have anyone tried porting windows driver code to Linux, and struck in replacing the WaitForMultipleObjects API to Linux.

WaitForSingleObject can be replaced with wait_event_interruptible..

But what about WaitForMultipleObjects.. I see post in which they are using pthread_cond_wait for user space application. What is the alternative for linux kernel space..

Thanks for your time..

Comment: Related, see [WaitForSingleObject and WaitForMultipleObjects equivalent in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2719580/608639).

Comment: I need a solution for kernel space and not user space

Answer (score 1):

You arrange so that multiple code paths that represent events call wake_up() on same waitqueue.
This will be equivalent of WaitForMultipleObjects with false WaitAll.

How to know which event occurred: one possibility is to use a wake-up variant with a little known "key" parameter: `wake_up_poll()` and its friends. See `linux/wait.h`. The "key" parameter should be unique for every event. Then, customize the wake handler function of the wait queue (of type `wait_queue_func_t`). It accepts four arguments; the "key" is the last one, unused by the default handler. "Subclass" it and use the "key" arg to identify who has waked.

For WaitAll=true, keep waiting until all events occur.